# After formatting and installing Ubuntu 15.10, and gnome-session-flashback, cannot view desktop icons or drag anything to the desktop

Tags: gnome

I installed a brand-new Ubuntu 15.10 (formatted previous installation), and installed gnome-session-flashback (`sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback`).

I cannot drag anything to the desktop. There is no contextual menu for cut, copy, paste, create empty document, or anything like that when I right-click the desktop. A folder named Escritorio (such name appears when you use spanish language) exists in my user and I can put files there, but it does not get reflected in the screen. Attached image with the problem.

How can I fix that?

[image: Cannot see the IntelliJ icon, nor see any useful contextual menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

1. Open `dconf-editor` (`Alt+F2` and write `dconf-editor`).
2. Search for `org > gnome > desktop > background` and check the `show-desktop-icons` button.